# What is the time complexity for PriorityQueue added in .NET 6

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-6.0

I came along learning built-in types in C#, and now interested in PriorityQueue [introduced in .NET 6](https://github.com/pgolebiowski/dotnet-runtime-fork/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs)

I'm wondering what is the time complexity for the common operations like:

- Heapify an unordered array
- Dequeue an element
- Enqueue an element

Thanks!

Comment: **Heapify:** `O(n * log(n))`, **Dequeue:** `O(log(n))`, **Enqueue:** `O(log(n))`

Comment: It's implemented as min-heap (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0), so complexity characteristics of that structure apply.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `PriorityQueue` class is implemented [as a min heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> Implements an array-backed, quaternary min-heap.

Moreover the source code is on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs).

We can then know the time complexities are as follows:

- Heapify an unordered array:

  If the collection is passed [to the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-priorityqueue-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-valuetuple((-0-1)))))), the time complexity will be O(*n*). This is already suggested by the comment in the documentation:

  > Constructs the heap using a heapify operation, which is generally faster than enqueuing individual elements sequentially.

  ...but confirmed by the code we find for [Heapify](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs#L630). It implements the O(*n*) algorithm mentioned at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap).
- Dequeue an element

  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract) describes the algorithm and concludes:

  > the delete operation has a time complexity relative to the height of the tree, or O(log *n*).

  It is this algorithm that is implemented by [Dequeue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs#L241).
- Enqueue an element

  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert) describes the algorithm and concludes:

  > the insertion operation has a worst-case time complexity of O(log *n*). For a random heap, and for repeated insertions, the insertion operation has an average-case complexity of O(1)

  It is this algorithm that is implemented by [Enqueue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs#L197).

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: What is the time complexity of PriorityQueue.Count?

Comment: @SteveScott most likely O(1), I haven't looked at the code, but it usually keeps the count updated.